# Broken unsubscribe link in footer of Careers invite

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email

The unsubscribe link in a Careers invitation email I just received is invalid:

```
<a href="http://http://careers.stackoverflow.com//email/optout/jeremy@jeremybanks.ca/XXXXXXX">click here</a>
         ^      ^                               ^^
```

[image]

Comment: The double slash may not necessarily be wrong but is also not promising.

Comment: Confirmed, we're working on a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed...thanks for pointing it out!